# Selenium RC memory leak

Tags: java, memory, selenium

Im trying to run Selenium RC with Nagios3.
Everything works ok up to 3h... then selenium engine takes sometimes even 1.4G RAM and stop responding.

I'm starting selenium by:

java -server -Xss64k -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xverify:none -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+UseParallelGC -jar /usr/local/selenium/selenium-server.jar -log /var/log/selenium-server.log -browserSideLog  &> /var/log/selenium-server.log &

Any idea how to limit memory aviable to selenium? Or how to dectect/fix memory leak

Comment: Please post some of the output from -XX:+PrintGCDetails at the end when the application becomes unresponsive.

Comment: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError can be useful if the app is completely running out of memory.

Comment: OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with both selenium-server-1.0.3.jar and selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar (the latest download). I've also pulled the latest source for the server, and most of the changes from patch mentioned below are there (one of the files is no longer there). So, there's still a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

There was a memory leak in Selenium RC and this has been fixed when the patch in [issue 814](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?can=2&q=814&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&id=814) was applied. If you get the latest [server](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.0a6.jar) you shouldnt have this issue

Answer (score 0):

Problem was java 1.5... with 1.6 working ok.

EDIT: Well, not realy, now java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: After 3 days stable working, today in logs:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at [OutOfMemory exception selenium server 2.0b3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749725/outofmemory-exception-selenium-server-2-0b3/5921992#5921992) and discussion / patches linked to therein.

There are memory leaks in the logging code for selenium-server. There are some patches more recent than 2.0b3, even. If you can't apply the patches, turning off logging should fix it in the meantime, or at least confirm that that is the source of the problem. It took care of it for me.