# OutOfMemory exception selenium server 2.0b3

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We just deployed selenium server 2.0b3 (upgraded from 1.0.3).  It
looks like there are some fairly serious memory leaks - OutOfMemory
exception thrown during runs longer than 30 minutes long.

Is there any straight forward workaround for dealing with the memory leaks in the
2.0b3 selenium server?

I was hoping to get the 2.0b3 source, apply the assorted patches
submitted thus far and use this.  However, when I pull this:

svn checkout http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/tags/selenium-2.0-beta-3/
selenium-2.0-beta-3

and build with

./go clean release

The resulting binaries don't appear to have the
DefaultSelenium.class.  Not sure what is going on here...

Alternately, I thought maybe we will just start working with the
latest release candidate.  However, looks like the
DefaultSelenium.class is not here either.

Do I need to upgrade the client code to use WebDriver?  I thought
things were suppose to be backwards compatible.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

for backwards compatibility you should use the WebdriverBackedSelenium like this:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //or any of the other drivertypes

Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, START_URL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically what kind of OutOfMemoryException is getting thrown? Heap? GC overhead limit? other?

I was getting "GC overhead limit exceeded" and sometimes also "out of heap space" as the message within the Exception (both 1.0.3 and 2.0.b3, using ruby selenium-client-1.2.18), and found your thread on the selenium-developers google group.[1] Have you followed along with the responses there?

Turning logging off for selenium-server (both `-log` AND `-browserSideLog`) stopped the OOMEs for me. I can wait till the next selenium-server release to get Kristian's patches.[2]

[1] http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-developers/browse_thread/thread/30d38475a16985a9/0db1af2456304f9f?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=outofmemory#0db1af2456304f9f

[2] http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=11872